# Processing a list of states to a state with a list value

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to understand Monads and States right now.

I have been tasked with writing a function with the following signature, with the only implementation details supplied being "there is only one reasonable implementation of this function":

```
f :: [State.State s a] -> State.State s [a]
```

I do not fully understand States but what I understand from this question is that beginning with a list of states I want to chain their calling such that I end up with one final state and a list of results along the way.

Trying that chaining idea, I have no idea how to even begin with that concept. I am very likely missing something conceptually that maybe someone can shed some light on?

Comment: Not only is there only one reasonable implementation, it's already implemented by a standard function. Hint: `State.State s` is a monad, and `[]` is a traversable.

Comment: Note that this will use exactly 0 details from the `State` type. This is just a special case of  `Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`. It exists in the standard libraries already, but you definitely should be aware of how to do it yourself.

Comment: I wasn't able to wrap my head around the bind operation and how it passes through the value, it makes a lot more sense now especially when abstracting away `State` and just thinking about `Monad`. Thanks!

Comment: The Monad instance for `State` does look pretty scary on paper - the key is to realise that all it's doing is manually threading the state through to ensure that the successive actions will always "see" the most recently updated state value.

Comment: @ZiyadEdher If you've got a handle on this now, you should write up an answer yourself.

Comment: Was planning on doing that tonight :)

Comment: Is it really *unreasonable* to run the computations in reverse order? Clearly it's less obvious than the normal implementation, but I don't know if I would go so far as to say there's only one reasonable implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a function that takes a list of states. Normally, you pattern match on lists, so let's do that.

```
f [] = ???
f (x:xs) = ???
```

If we get the empty list, then we probably want to return the empty list, but wrapped in the `State` monad. That's what the `return` function does.

```
f [] = return []
f (x:xs) = ???
```

Now, we need to return a `State` monad for the other case. The way you usually work with monads is with `do` notation.

```
f [] = return []
f (x:xs) = do
  ???
```

Now, `x` is a `State` monad, and xs is a list of `State` monads. Because we're writing a pattern-matching list function, we probably want to recurse somewhere in the `do` block.

I think it should be fairly straightforward from here.